# doc.save() throwing error with jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

When I try and use the save() function for jsPDF it's throwing the following error:

ReferenceError: saveAs is not defined

I'm just trying a very simple example:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

doc.save('test.pdf');
```

Anyone have any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Found out what the issue was. The saveAs function is part of [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) so I just needed to include this and everything worked.

Comment: Pretty certain I can't due to the fact that I don't have enough points.

Comment: My god this library is a joke. Warning: don't bother with jsPDF

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough to comment yet, so I'm adding this as an answer... `saveAs()` is a w3c interface. If adding FileSaver fixed your issue, that means you were using an old browser; FileSaver.js is used as a shim for jsPDF to support older browsers that don't have that function natively.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use jspdf.debug.js it contains all of the plugins in one file. This way you are covered if something else is needed.

-Cheers

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.text(30, 30, 'Hello world!');
        pdf.save('hello_world.pdf');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer as this post has been found in low quality post. Code only and 'try this' answers are discouraged as it doesn't provide any searchable content and why people should 'try this'.