# jsPDF Output PDF Download

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I'm creating a PDF using jsPDF (https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).
It's very basic, but suffices to do the job.
To actually create the before defined PDF I use
`doc.output ('datauri');`.

The Doc's are very poor, I don't know what output types are available and if it matters.
It's very hard to find anything about this on Google; jsPDF seems to be not so common as is should be.
It opens the PDF but I want the PDF to start downloading as a file.
I want this dialog to open, that ask if I want to save or open.
I hope anyone understands what I'm trying to do.

I found a list of all outputtypes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18098815/3123142 What I want is:

```
doc.output ('save', 'filename.pdf');
```

But it throws an error: "Error in function jsPDF/output: saveAs is not defined" How to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [doc.save() throwing error with jspdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340194/doc-save-throwing-error-with-jspdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it my own:
In my zip of jsPDF wans't a working FileSaver.js so i downloaded it again from github https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js and linked it in the head, now everything works just fine.